# Is it possible to interact with a console while running a windows desktop application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, desktop-application

I know that you can create a separate console application, however, I am in the final stages of testing and my application does not have an interface. Is there a way to simply open a console and interact with that inside the desktop application? This would be in a test method. (I am using C#, in Visual Studio 2008).

Thanks,

badPanda

Comment: In case anyone else is reading this, the solution I ended up using was to write directly to the debug window. However, AllocConsole and FreeConsole do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do what you want using `AllocConsole` (creates a new console) or `AttachConsole` (attaches to an existing console), but I think there are some limitations to what you can do with them.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the API documentation for `AllocConsole` and [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.allocconsole)'s the PInvoke page.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)'s a list of lots of Console functions, might be something else useful there too.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be helpful, but some of the same techniques of GUI testing can be applied to a console app too, of course.

Here is an [article and example code in C# for a user interface test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163738.aspx).

Or there are totally different tools/languages that can be used for UI testing, such as [AutoIt v3](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml), which is easy to learn and apply. AutoIt does have a DLL/COM control that you can access from your preferred programming language (but I haven't used it that way so I can't comment on how well it works).

Comment: I'm actually not doing any UI testing. The only piece of my application that involves the windows forms is a system tray icon.
But thanks.